# Do I require authorization from Spotify for isrc code?

Tags: spotify

I want to make a request to [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/), getting the isrc code based on song title and artist title.
Do I require authorization for this type of request?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to authenticate your request, though it's advisable if you are going to make lots of requests.

You would use the [Search endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/) for finding tracks with a given title and artist name, and then you would get the data for the track using the [Get a track endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-track/).

There you can find the `isrc` code in the `external_ids` field.